# Invalid number of channels in input image, K Clusters, COLOR_BGR2GRAY

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a program in a jupyter notebook that uses k means to segment an image by using dominant color color clusters. It works well, now I try to add some code from a PyCharm program that draws lines on the image using thresholding. Now I am getting this error at the bottom.

```py
!pip install opencv-python
!pip install sklearn

import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\holli\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\python photos\\lau black short changing room, haair.jpg')
image.shape

x,y,z= image.shape

plt.imshow(image)

img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

plt.imshow(img)

img = img.reshape(-1,3)

dominant_color = 6
model = KMeans(dominant_color)
model.fit(img)

colors = model.cluster_centers_

colors = np.array(colors, dtype="uint8")

colors

colors = np.array(colors, dtype="uint8")

for i in range(new_image.shape[0]):
    new_image[i] = colors[model.labels_[i]]

new_image = np.reshape(new_image, (x,y,z))

plt.imshow(new_image)

model.labels_

blurred = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
grey_blur = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(grey_blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 5)
combined = cv2.bitwise_and(new_image, new_image, mask=thresh)
cv2.imshow("cartoon Lau blk shrt", combined)

reg_img = cv2.cvtColor(new_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

cv2.imwrite('C:\\Users\\holli\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\python photos\\lai_img_seg.jpg', reg_img)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-9346139ce50d> in <module>
      1 blurred = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
----> 2 grey_blur = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      3 thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(grey_blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 5)
      4 combined = cv2.bitwise_and(new_image, new_image, mask=thresh)
      5 cv2.imshow("cartoon Lau blk shrt", combined)

error: OpenCV(4.5.3) c:\users\runneradmin\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-c2l3r8zm\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous namespace'::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xb6623f80::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xb6623f80::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 1
```

I think that I may be able to write/save the "blurred" image then read it back in and perform the other tasks on it. If that doesn't work I will not know what else to do.

Can anyone see anything in my code that might cause this "invalid number of channels in input image:" error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img` has an unsuitable shape.

If you want it to be BGR (for cvtColor), it must be `(something, something, 3)`.

After your reshaping (flattening), it only has two dimensions because you gave it the shape `(-1, 3)`... which cvtColor interprets to mean a single-channel (grayscale) image.

You could reshape it to be `(-1, 1, 3)`, which is a long column of color pixels:

```py
img.shape = (-1, 1, 3)
```

Comment: I used this method and it worked, I forgot that color variable